# c# xml request with a xml file

Tags: c#, xml, service, request, response

I must retrieve data from a url (http://data.com:7900). And for that the tech guys sent me an **DTD**, **XMLRequest** and a **XMLResponse** **file**. I don't know much about those things. I guess sending the whole XMLRequest to the service (url) gets me a response from the service (XMLResponse). The DTD is to verify the XML format. But...

How do I get the job done with C#?

PS: It would also help me to test that with a tool (GUI, CMD, ...), to get sure everything is alright with the service.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it!

```
        var xmlString = string.Empty;
        var xmlPath = "pathToFile.xml";
        if (File.Exists(xmlPath))
        {
            xmlString = File.ReadAllText(xmlPath);
        }
        var xmlBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlString);

        var url = "http://data.com:7000";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
        request.ContentLength = xmlBytes.Length;

        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(xmlBytes, 0, xmlBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); // the respond is in here!

        result.Close();
        response.Close();
```